# How to display x axis label for each matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to add an x axis label below each subplot. I use this code to create the charts:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax1.set_xlim([min(df1["Age"]),max(df1["Age"])])
ax1.set_xlabel("All Age Freq")
ax1 = df1["Age"].hist(color="cornflowerblue")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax2.set_xlim([min(df2["Age"]),max(df2["Age"])])
ax2.set_xlabel = "Survived by Age Freq"
ax2 = df2["Age"].hist(color="seagreen")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax3.set_xlim([min(df3["Age"]),max(df3["Age"])])
ax3.set_xlabel = "Not Survived by Age Freq"
ax3 = df3["Age"].hist(color="cadetblue")

plt.show()
```

This is how it looks. Only the first one shows

[image]

How can I show a different x axis label under each `subplot`?

Comment: The name of this post is very confusing.  It refers to the "title" of the axis, but what you actually mean is the "x-label" (the text under the x-axis).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `ax.set_xlabel` wrong, which is a **function** (first call is correct, the others are not):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax1.set_xlim([min(df1["Age"]),max(df1["Age"])])
ax1.set_xlabel("All Age Freq")  # CORRECT USAGE
ax1 = df1["Age"].hist(color="cornflowerblue")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax2.set_xlim([min(df2["Age"]),max(df2["Age"])])
ax2.set_xlabel = "Survived by Age Freq"  # ERROR set_xlabel is a function
ax2 = df2["Age"].hist(color="seagreen")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax3.set_xlim([min(df3["Age"]),max(df3["Age"])])
ax3.set_xlabel = "Not Survived by Age Freq"  # ERROR set_xlabel is a function
ax3 = df3["Age"].hist(color="cadetblue")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a title above each plot using:

```
ax.set_title('your title')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, just use [matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title), here's a little example out of your code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Age":[1,2,3,4]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Age":[10,20,30,40]
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Age":[100,200,300,400]
})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax1.set_title("Title for df1")
ax1.set_xlim([min(df1["Age"]), max(df1["Age"])])
ax1.set_xlabel("All Age Freq")
ax1 = df1["Age"].hist(color="cornflowerblue")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
ax2.set_xlim([min(df2["Age"]), max(df2["Age"])])
ax2.set_title("Title for df2")
ax2.set_xlabel = "Survived by Age Freq"
ax2 = df2["Age"].hist(color="seagreen")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
ax3.set_xlim([min(df3["Age"]), max(df3["Age"])])
ax3.set_title("Title for df3")
ax3.set_xlabel = "Not Survived by Age Freq"
ax3 = df3["Age"].hist(color="cadetblue")

plt.show()
```