# How to display x axis labels on all bar chart subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Problem:**

I am trying to display all of the labels on my bar chart subplots. I have tried everything in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912100/matplotlib-show-x-ticks-on-all-subplots-and-unique-y-label) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257712/how-to-display-x-axis-label-for-each-matplotlib-subplot) with no luck.

**Data:**

```
data = StringIO("""

Index-- --Rk    Passing-Player  Passing-Cmp Passing-Att Passing-Pct Passing-Yds Passing-Y/A Passing-AY/A    Passing-TD  Passing-Int Passing-Rate
0   0   1   Patrick Mahomes 364 573 63.5    4653    8.1 8.2 36  15  147.2
1   1   2   Davis Webb  22  41  53.7    300 7.3 8.3 2   0   131.2
2   2   3   Nic Shimonek    1   2   50.0    18  9.0 9.0 0   0   125.6
3   3   4   Jakeem Grant    1   1   100.0   72  72.0    92.0    1   0   1034.8
4   4   5   Jonathan Giles  1   1   100.0   3   3.0 3.0 0   0   125.2
5   5   6   Ian Sadler  0   1   0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0

""")

df = pd.read_table(data, delim_whitespace=True)

dfs = [df] * 9
```

**Plotting code:**

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(10,10), sharey=True, sharex=False)
for ax,df in zip(axs.ravel(), dfs):
    ax.bar(df['Passing-Player'], df['Passing-Yds'])
    for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
        tick.set_visible(True)

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
fig.tight_layout(pad=2.0, w_pad=2.0, h_pad=10.0)
fig.savefig("tester.png")
```

**Result:**

[image]

How can I display all of the x axis labels because in my real data each plot is different with different player names.

Comment: are you running python 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)` as you aren't using dates and set the tick labels yourself with a rotation using `ax.set_xticklabels(labels_go_here, rotation=90)`

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(10,10), sharey=True, sharex=False)
for ax, df in zip(axs.ravel(), dfs):
    ax.bar(df['Passing-Player'], df['Passing-Yds'])
    ax.set_xticklabels(df['Passing-Player'], rotation=90)

fig.tight_layout(pad=2.0, w_pad=2.0, h_pad=10.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]